# How to take Taylor expansion of matrix?

Tags: taylor-expansion, matrix-calculus

Assume I have a function $f: R^{n\times n} \rightarrow R^{n\times n}$.
What's the Taylor expansion of f ?

e.g. $f(X) = X^n$ where $X$ is a matrix.

then what is Taylor expansion of $f(X+Y)$ at X ?

Comment: For $X^p$, the first-order expansion is
$$F(X+Y) = F(X) + \sum_{k=1}^p X^{k-1}\,Y\,X^{p-k}$$

Comment: @greg Thanks for your input. What if the function is not poly in X. Say having the gradient of f w.r.t X, How to integrate the gradient into the Taylor form?